# Converting batch script with GOTO to single line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know that "&" and "&&" will have to be used here. But what about GOTO? How to make it work with labels or without? I want it to look like for example: echo %time% & dir & echo %time%.

```
@echo off
:start
cls
echo -create (create password)
echo -check (check password)
echo.
set /p PROGRAM= What do you want to do?: 
goto %PROGRAM%

:create
cls
set /p PASSWORD= What do you want your password to be?: 
echo %PASSWORD% > test.txt
pause
goto start

:check
cls
set /p PASSWORD1= What is your password?

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
set TEXT=%%a
)

if %PASSWORD1%==%TEXT% goto correct
echo you are wrong!!!
pause
goto start

:correct
echo you are right!!!
pause
goto start
```

Comment: don't use `goto`, use `call :label` intead

Comment: ...also `goto %program%` why? why not create array elements instead and give numeric values using a choice command? it is far easier typing `1`, `2` or `3` than typing `create` or `check`

Comment: where exactly in this are you planning on chaining commands? if you are more specific, I could help, else I will just give an example answer. Finally, please do realise that there is a big difference between `&` and `&&` the latter will only execute next command, if previous command has `errorlevel 0` where `&` will run second command regardless of errorlevel.

Comment: it does not work `@echo off && :start && echo -create (create password) && call :start`

Comment: I want to run from cmd.exe /c

Comment: where are you planning to get the labels from on commandline? Please explain exactly what you want to do.

Comment: for example, I want the program to work from a single command line, I want to do it

Comment: you cannot call batch labels outside of a batch script. you can simply test it by doing from `cmd` type `call :start` and see the  message. There are some ways to do something similar, but the amount of code is unreadable, hence batch file existence.

Comment: I do not care for the code to be readable, it's important that it works

Comment: but you cannot call labels outside a batch file.. so for instance `goto start` won't work.

Comment: I understand, therefore, I need a similar solution without the use of goto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, as already commented, it is not possible to use labels in the command line.

Under the premises in your question, your best option is to enclose each of the routines in `if / else` commands and replace the looping to the start with an infinite loop. So, you end with something like this (the "readable" prototype)

```cmd
for /l %a in (0) do ( 
    cls
    & echo -create (create password)
    & echo -check (check password)
    & echo/
    & set pass=
    & set p=
    & set /p p=What do you want to do?
    & cls 
    & (if !p!==create (
        set /p pass=What do you want your password to be?:
        & (echo !pass!)>test.txt
    ) else if !p!==check (
        set /p pass=What is your password?
        & set /p text=<test.txt 
        & if !pass!==!text! (
            echo You are right !!!
        ) else (
            echo You are wrong !!!
        )
    ) else (
        echo wrong command !!!
    ))
    & echo/ & pause 
)
```

Notes:

- The `goto :start` is now a infinite `for /l` loop.
- Every command that is continuation of the previous one needs a `&` operator. The first command inside a `if` or `else` block should not have it.
- As we are changing variables and retrieving the changed value inside the same line, we will need to use delayed expansion (`!var!`).
- As delayed expansion will be used in command line, we will need to include some switches in `cmd` call

Now, with everything in a line:

```cmd
cmd /e /v /c"for /l %a in (0) do ( cls & echo -create (create password) & echo -check (check password) & echo/ & set pass= & set p= & set /p p=What do you want to do? & cls & (if !p!==create ( set /p pass=What do you want your password to be?: & (echo !pass!)>test.txt ) else if !p!==check ( set /p pass=What is your password? & set /p text=<test.txt & if !pass!==!text! ( echo You are right !!! ) else ( echo You are wrong !!! ) ) else ( echo wrong command !!! )) & echo/ & pause )"
```

The `/e` (enable extensions, usually already enabled, but just in case), `/v` (enable delayed expansion) switches are included to ensure the new `cmd` instance is create with the required configuration.

And, in any case, remember that the longest command line you can write is 8191 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
for /L %a in () do ( 
    cls
    & echo 1- Create password
    & echo 2- Check password
    & echo/
    & choice /N /C 12 /M "What do you want to do? "
    & cls 
    & (if not errorlevel 2 (
        set /p "pass=What do you want your password to be?: "
        & (call echo %%pass%%)>test.txt
    ) else (
        set /p "pass=What is your password? "
        & (call echo %%pass%%)>text.txt
        & fc test.txt text.txt >nul
        & if not errorlevel 1 (
            echo You are right !!!
        ) else (
            echo You are wrong !!!
        )
    ))
    & echo/ & pause 
)
```

This is the one-liner version that you must put on the command-line:

```
for /L %a in () do (cls & echo 1- Create password & echo 2- Check password & echo/& choice /N /C 12 /M "What do you want to do? " & cls & ( if not errorlevel 2 (set /p "pass=What do you want your password to be?: " & (call echo %^pass%)>test.txt) else (set /p "pass=What is your password?: " & (call echo %^pass%)>text.txt & fc test.txt text.txt >nul & if not errorlevel 1 (echo You are right !!!) else (echo You are wrong !!!)) ) & echo/ & pause)
```

In order to execute this line in a `cmd.exe` invocation, just enclose the whole line between quotes:

```
cmd /C "for /L %a in () do ( ... pause)"
```

It is simpler to use `choice` command for the option selection. Besides, doing that also allows to use `if errorlevel` form than don't requires Delayed Expansion... The same point apply for the password comparison via `fc` command.

Tested on Windows 8.1